# Javascript, have different buttons call different functions

Tags: javascript, button

I have two different functions following this format

```
$("button1").click(function(){ .... });
$("button2").click(function(){ .... });
```

I assumed I could create buttons with different ID values like so....

```
<button id="button1">Button1</button>
<button id="button2">Button1</button>
```

And then this button would call whichever function has the proper ID value tied to it...

But for some reason it's not working. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: jQuery selectors work just like CSS selectors. Review your code with that in mind.

Comment: @elclanrs They don't behave *exactly* equal though.. For once, they only query elements currently present in the DOM. And of course, Sizzle provides many extensions that regular CSS selectors do not have but this is off-topic. `=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#button1").click(function(){ .... });
$("#button2").click(function(){ .... });
```

You need the # character to note an id in JQuery

Answer (score 3):

Use `#` to access the id:

```
$('#button1').click...
```

and to access classes, use a dot:

```
$('.myclass').click(...)
```

Comment: and a button element with $('button')... :)